# Create subdict from main dict

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary of a string of time ranges, like:

```
{'10:00-12:00': 'Maths',
 '13:00-15:00': 'Physics',
 '16:00-18:00': 'History',
 '19:00-22:00': 'Biology',
 '23:00-01:00': 'Chemistry',
 '02:00-04:00': 'Computer',
 '05:00-10:00': 'English'}
```

Now I want to extract the end time, like `12:00` and `13:00` from the dictionary and make make a dictionary with the name of the second subject.

**So the output I want is**:

```
{'12:00-13:00':'Physics',
 '15:00-16:00':'History',
 '18:00-19:00':'Biology',
 '22:00-23:00':'Chemistry',
 '01:00-02:00':'Computer',
 '04:00-05:00':'English'}
```

I could just make this dictionary myself(by hardwire the values), but I wanted this to be dynamic because the keys are the column name of a dataframe(from csv) and the values are the field  name. So I wanted python to pick it up dynamically based on the csv. I have tried using `zip(lst,lst[1:])` but it doesn't work with dictionary as indexing is different for dictionary.
Ive also tried using:

```
data = {'10:00-12:00': 'Maths',
        '13:00-15:00': 'Physics',
        '16:00-18:00': 'History',
        '19:00-22:00': 'Biology',
        '23:00-01:00': 'Chemistry',
        '02:00-04:00': 'Computer',
        '05:00-10:00': 'English'}

def pairwise(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    a = next(it, None)

    for b in it:
        yield (a, b)
        a = b

a = pairwise(data)
print(list(a)) #[('10:00-12:00', '13:00-15:00'), ('13:00-15:00', '16:00-18:00'), ('16:00-18:00', '19:00-22:00'), ('19:00-22:00', '23:00-01:00'), ('23:00-01:00', '02:00-04:00'), ('02:00-04:00', '05:00-10:00')]
#not the keys of the desired output
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're better off first parsing the date time ranges into a proper datatype like `datetime` & then doing the manipulations. Playing with time strings is only going to lead to countless headaches.

Comment: @rdas Actually later on im looping through the dict, making them datetime.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Ive edited it,Is it better now?

Comment: Just to be clear: Is your goal to *calculate the pause* before a session (maths is ...-12:00 and physics is 13:00-... => 12:00-13:00) or just to get *the hour before* a session (physics is 13:00-... => 12:00-13:00)? Since all pauses are one hour long for this data, both approaches yield the same results.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Actually yes, the time difference between math and physics is 1 but it can increase or decrease too, that is im trying to get check if current time lies between this 12:00 and 13:00 so for that i wanted to extract 12:00 and 13:00. 12:00 and 13:00 could also be something like 12:00 and 13:30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you what you want

```
a = {'10:00-12:00': 'Maths', '13:00-15:00': 'Physics', '16:00-18:00': 'History', '19:00-22:00': 'Biology', '23:00-01:00': 'Chemistry', '02:00-04:00': 'Computer', '05:00-10:00': 'English'}

keys_split = list(map(lambda s: s.split("-"), a.keys()))
flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
ks = flatten(keys_split)
keys_tmp= list(zip(ks[1::2],ks[2::2]))
keys_res = list(map(lambda e: e[0]+'-'+e[1], keys_tmp))
values_res = list(a.values())[1:]
dict_res = dict(zip(keys_res, values_res))
```

and when printing will look like this

```
print(dict_res)
#{'12:00-13:00': 'Physics', '15:00-16:00': 'History', '18:00-19:00': 'Biology', '22:00-23:00': 'Chemistry', '01:00-02:00': 'Computer', '04:00-05:00': 'English'}
```

**explanation on what's going on:**

- line1: a.keys() will give you all keys, each key is a string
- line1: map takes a lambda function that iterates over all strings (s), that we saw in a.keys() and splits them by '-'

```
print(a.keys())
# dict_keys(['10:00-12:00', '13:00-15:00', '16:00-18:00', '19:00-22:00', '23:00-01:00', '02:00-04:00', '05:00-10:00'])
print(keys_split)
# [['10:00', '12:00'], ['13:00', '15:00'], ['16:00', '18:00'], ['19:00', '22:00'], ['23:00', '01:00'], ['02:00', '04:00'], ['05:00', '10:00']]
```

- line2: flatten is a lambda function that iterates through a list l and flattens a list of lists to a simple list
- line3: apply flatten on keys_split to get a flat list

```
print(ks)
# ['10:00', '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', '16:00', '18:00', '19:00', '22:00', '23:00', '01:00', '02:00', '04:00', '05:00', '10:00']
```

- line4: create a temporary list by zip over list 1 (ks[1::2]) with new start-timestamps 12:00, 15:00, 16:00 etc. and over list 2 (k2[2::2]) with new end-timestamps 13:00, 16:00, 19:00 etc.
- line5: to obtain the keys in the format you wanted, map over all elements of temporary list to concat the elements with '-' in between e.g. '12:00-13:00', '15:00-16:00' etc.

```
print(keys_tmp)
#[('12:00', '13:00'), ('15:00', '16:00'), ('18:00', '19:00'), ('22:00', '23:00'), ('01:00', '02:00'), ('04:00', '05:00')]
print(keys_res)
#['12:00-13:00', '15:00-16:00', '18:00-19:00', '22:00-23:00', '01:00-02:00', '04:00-05:00']
```

- line6: get all values from dict a, but leave out first element
- line7: final dict_res is the zip over two lists keys_res and values_res

```
print(values_res)
#['Physics', 'History', 'Biology', 'Chemistry', 'Computer', 'English']
```

Hope this makes it a bit clearer, just go line by line and print out to see what's going on :)

Comment: You got a typo there on line 5, `keys_split`

Comment: Thanks! This works dynamically too, though i have no idea what's going on, maybe include a bit of information as to, what's happening here too.

Comment: yeah sure will add information now, also if you print out the variables, it will also help what's going on

Comment: I think making a function out of this and passing dictionary as a argument is better right?

Comment: Yes if you have to apply this logic again over other dicts, it makes sense to define it as a function

Answer (score 2):

```
import more_itertools
from collections import namedtuple

data = {'10:00-12:00': 'Maths', '13:00-15:00': 'Physics',
        '16:00-18:00': 'History', '19:00-22:00': 'Biology', 
        '23:00-01:00': 'Chemistry', '02:00-04:00': 'Computer', 
        '05:00-10:00': 'English'}

Item = namedtuple('Item', ('start', 'end', 'subject'))
def parse(item):
    times, subject = item
    start, end = times.split('-')
    return Item(start, end, subject)

def generate_items(data):
    for item1, item2 in more_itertools.windowed(data,2):
        yield f'{item1.end}-{item2.start}', item2.subject

data = [parse(item) for item in data.items()]
print(dict(generate_items(data)))
```

output

```
{'12:00-13:00': 'Physics', '15:00-16:00': 'History', '18:00-19:00': 'Biology', '22:00-23:00': 'Chemistry', '01:00-02:00': 'Computer', '04:00-05:00': 'English'}
```

[more-iterools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) package is convenient, but `more_itertools.windowed()` can be be replaced with something like `zip(data[:-1], data[1:])`

```
from collections import namedtuple

data = {'10:00-12:00': 'Maths', '13:00-15:00': 'Physics',
        '16:00-18:00': 'History', '19:00-22:00': 'Biology', 
        '23:00-01:00': 'Chemistry', '02:00-04:00': 'Computer', 
        '05:00-10:00': 'English'}


Item = namedtuple('Item', ('start', 'end', 'subject'))
def parse(item):
    times, subject = item
    start, end = times.split('-')
    return Item(start, end, subject)

def generate_items(data):
    for item1, item2 in zip(data[:-1], data[1:]):
        yield f'{item1.end}-{item2.start}', item2.subject

data = [parse(item) for item in data.items()]
print(dict(generate_items(data)))
```

Comment: `more_itertools` ? neat.

Comment: This solution is dynamic as well, have no clue what is happening, but this works here. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to do this using datetime.time converted times,
but you can do it on a pure string basis *without any imports* :

```
s = {'10:00-12:00': 'Maths',      '13:00-15:00': 'Physics',
     '16:00-18:00': 'History',    '19:00-22:00': 'Biology',
     '23:00-01:00': 'Chemistry',  '02:00-04:00': 'Computer',
     '05:00-10:00': 'English'}

# this is very explicit - you can reduce the amount of variables used
# by making the comprehensions bigger - but for SO I prefer readability 

# extract end times and convert to int
times = [ tuple(map(int, (t.split("-")[1]).split(":"))) for t in s.keys()][:-1]

# get lectures
what = list(s.values())[1:]
print(times, what, sep="\n") 

# create new schedule with end times
new_sched= [f"{v1:02d}:{v2:02d}-{v1+1:02d}:{v2:02d}" for (v1,v2) in times]

# construct new scheduling
m = {}
for when,wh in zip(new_sched,what):
    m[when] = wh

# check 
print(m)
print( {'12:00-13:00':'Physics', '15:00-16:00':'History',
'18:00-19:00':'Biology', '22:00-23:00':'Chemistry',
'01:00-02:00':'Computer', '04:00-05:00':'English'})
```

Output:

```
# parsed end times as tuple of integers
[(12, 0), (15, 0), (18, 0), (22, 0), (1, 0), (4, 0)]
# extracted lectures
['Physics', 'History', 'Biology', 'Chemistry', 'Computer', 'English']

# constructed dict
{'12:00-13:00': 'Physics', '15:00-16:00': 'History', 
 '18:00-19:00': 'Biology', '22:00-23:00': 'Chemistry', 
 '01:00-02:00': 'Computer', '04:00-05:00': 'English'}
# given result dict
{'12:00-13:00': 'Physics', '15:00-16:00': 'History', 
 '18:00-19:00': 'Biology', '22:00-23:00': 'Chemistry', 
 '01:00-02:00': 'Computer', '04:00-05:00': 'English'}
```

Comment: It worked with the initial dictionary but as i changed the csv(hence changing my dictionary), I get the same result as the initial dict, before

Comment: @Cool not sure what you mean. I edited to also include the minutes part as part of the solution.

Comment: @Cool This uses the END-time of Maths as start time for Physics, All new lectures are 1h long. It uses the old starttime of Physics for History and it also is 1 h long, etc.

Comment: It works with this logic, but I tried changing the time gap and it did not work, so was curious, anyway Thanks for this answer with 0 imports, great! I was able to understand more nested list comprehension.